# MVC5 reading Config values without using System.Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config

I keep reading that the new MVC avoids using System.Web by default as that used to add lots of extra stuff automatically.

Does that mean that in order to read the config file now in MVC5, 
one should use from System.Net instead?

Thanks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be:

```
string key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AppKey");
```

OR

```
string key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppKey"];
```

Answer (score 6):

I read somewhere in a Microsoft example where they imported

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and then use the standard

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]
```

Just thought to post this in case somebody has the same question/problem